# Having difficulty wrapping text

Tags: ios, uilabel, word-wrap, sizetofit

I use the following code to add text in IOS

```
//Set up label frame
UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 210, 80)];
self.answer_text_label = tempLabel;
[tempLabel release];    
[self.preview_answer_container addSubview:self.answer_text_label];

//Populate label with text
self.answer_text_label.text = self.answer.text;
self.answer_text_label.numberOfLines = 4;
self.answer_text_label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
[self.answer_text_label sizeToFit];
```

However, the result I get is as such, the text seems to overflow to the right instead of staying within the frame as stipulated in my label setup 'CGRectMake(100, 10, 210, 80)'

[image]

The wrapping works if I change to `self.answer_text_label.numberOfLines = 0`. But this will not work for me since I need to constrain the text within my stipulated label frame.

Any way I can wrap the text and keep to only 4 lines?

EDIT:

Try the suggested code

```
self.answer_text_label.text = self.answer.text;
[self.answer_text_label sizeToFit];
CGRect labelRect = self.answer_text_label.frame;
labelRect.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(labelRect);
labelRect.size = self.answer_text_label.frame.size;
self.answer_text_label.frame = labelRect;
```

result as follows. Did not seem to solve my problem

[image]

Comment: if you are setting number of lines explicitly then you need to take care of label height by yourself, then only it will be wrapped properly.

Comment: But I did set the label height to be 80 when I am setting up my label frame. Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: and also I did explicitly set the width of label as well (210)

Comment: check the answer, and see if it works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting frame explicitly -

```
[self.answer_text_label sizeToFit];
CGRect labelRect = self.answer_text_label.frame;
labelRect.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(labelRect);
labelRect.size = self.answer_text_label.frame.size;
self.answer_text_label.frame = labelRect;
```

EDIT - Don't need to use this, just use following -
remove these of code just use below, no other property of frame, remove sizeToFit as well -

```
self.answer_text_label.numberOfLines = 4;
self.answer_text_label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

For vertical alignment - (With above line of code, use this as well, and do don't use size to fit)

```
    CGSize textSize = [self.answer_text_label.text sizeWithFont:self.answer_text_label.font 
                                constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.answer_text_label.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                                    lineBreakMode:self.answer_text_label.lineBreakMode];
self.answer_text_label.frame = CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, textSize.width, textSize.height);
```

Comment: Hmmm, I am still getting the same problem. See my updated question

Comment: @Zhen - this time i have tried on my machine and this works, just try and let me know if it works for you as well.

Comment: The problem is that if the text is less than 4 lines, the label will not be vertically aligned to the top, but stays in the middle of my container. That was the reason I used sizeToFit. So that it stays at the top

Comment: that's great. Your latest solution works! Thank you so much. I just needed to change the constrain height to the height of my original answer label frame.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 and later, use `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`, not UILineBreakModeWordWrap.

```
self.answer_text_label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```